# How do you know what OS to use in hosting Coldfusion Apps?

Tags: coldfusion, operating-system, hosting

What factors play part in determining the OS to host?
Or is it a matter of preference? 
Would factors like using SQL be a hindrance when hosting in Linux?
Are there any real advantages of one over the other? E.g Performance, Scalability, Security
Thanks

Comment: pre CF9, standard edition cannot run in 64bit mode under Windows.  In CF9 std, that restriction has been removed.  In Linux, 32bit JVM can allocate close to 4GB of heap while Windows can only allocate ~1.2GB max.

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in general the answer to this relies on two factors: what you are comfortable with, and cost.

In general Windows hosting is going to be more then Linux hosting because there is a licensing cost.  In many cases, it's a reasonable cost, but it will be higher.

However, if you are only familiar with Windows, or require Windows only software like MSSQL, then the cost is irrelevant.  You're better off with Windows.

Anyone can argue one is better then the other on a features or security standpoint, but truthfully, both are perfectly useful and secure in the hands of **someone who knows how to properly run and secure them**.

In short... it depends.